Ignore validation error when calling .NET framework WCF service from a .NET 6.0 project
I have a .NET framework 4.8 project, which is calling a .NET 4.8 WCF service. I want to use https, but for now I have only self signed certificate, thus I simply ignore all validation errors:
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

var binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
{
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue,
};

binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

using (var client = new SampleService(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://localhost/SampleService/Service.svc")))
{
    var response = client.GetConfiguration();
}

Everything works fine, but now I created another project with .NET 6.0 which is calling the same WCF service. Now, I am getting an error:

Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'localhost'.

Seems like this delegate:
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

is never hit, which is causing problems. After doing some research I tried for example this:
using (var client = new SampleService(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://localhost/SampleService/Service.svc")))
{
    client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new System.ServiceModel.Security.X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
    {
        CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
        RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
    };
    var response = client.GetConfiguration();
}

but it requires System.IdentityModel.dll, which is never copied to output directory. If I force Visual Studio to do so, it still shows that error and this dll was not found. Any ideas what can I do here?

.NET 6 is .NET Core 6, not .NET Framework. You can't use .NET Framework techniques in .NET Core, never mind that disabling validation is a bad idea. Instead of disabling certificate validation, trust the self-signed certificate on your development machine

.NET Core creates a self-signed certificate and adds it to the list of trusted certificates automatically or, through the dotnet dev-certs command. For other platforms, you can navigate to the site or service URL and add the certificate from the browser's padlock icon in the address bar. You can also use the Manage User Certificates tool

Okay, I take the suggestion. I checked some information and it seems that this code is automatically skipped for security reasons. Some people have used it on Core 2.0 before, and according to Microsoft's documentation, Core 6.0 can also be used. This is the document.
I have two ways to get you to add a self-signed certificate as trusted in a local test environment, you can try it:

"win+r"-entert "certlm.msc"-open Certificate Management Console

Choose "Trusted Root Certification Authorities""-Choose "ALL task"-Choose "import".



3.Go all the way to the next step and then choose your own certificate.
4.When you see it in the list, it will be added successfully.

Another way to do this, as mentioned in the comment above, is that in the development environment, you can set environment variables to tell the . .NET Core trusts specific certificates. This is very handy when developing, but should not be used in a production environment.
Open PowerShell, enter:
dotnet dev-certs https --trust -ep <cert>

"cert" is the location of your files.

The question asks why ServerCertificateValidationCallback is never hit. Putting that call in a constructor won't make it get called, it will only leak delegates.

@QI You but what if many people uses my program? They all have to import that certificate?

Actually, it's for security reasons. So I think it's still necessary. For example, many of our projects require customers to install corresponding certificates.
